# Percentage of lawn

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At each corner of a 16ft by 16ft square lawn there is a sprinkler that waters one quarter of a circle of 8 foot radius. In the center of the lawn, there is another sprinkler that waters a full circle of 8 foot radius. Part of the lawn is being watered by two sprinklers, and part of the lawn is being watered by only one sprinkler. What percentage of the lawn is being watered by two sprinklers?

16x16= 256 ft

one sprinkler covers: 1/4 of 8 ft. so 2 feet?

Second sprinkler covers: full 8 ft.

8x8=64

So to find the percentage of the two sprinklers would it be 64 ft. of the 256 ft.? just in percentage?

Answer (score 1):

Each corner sprinkler covers a quarter circle with radius $8$ feet.  It therefore covers $\frac 14 \pi 8^2=16\pi \approx 50.265 ft^2$  The center sprinkler covers $\pi 8^2=64\pi \approx 201.06 ft^2$.  The centers are $8\sqrt 2 ft$ apart.  There are four lens shaped areas that are covered by both the center sprinkler and a corner one.  You are supposed to compute the area of those lenses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 57%.

Area of the lawn being watered twice is the area of the 8 segments (assuming you have the figure made).

Comment: I got 35.6 % because the center sprinkler covers 201.06 ft leaving 54.94 of the 256 ft not covered by the center sprinkler. If I split that in half it is 27.47 ft on each side. If the 4 sprinklers each cover 50.265 ft. than the 22.795 is included and x4=91.1 of 256 ft which is 35.6%. Can you explain how you got 57%?